# How to achieve this using flexbox

Tags: flexbox

I've been having issues arranging post categories and a featured post div as displayed on the image.

Featured post W300px H300px 
Category Images W140 H140

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vuwz.png)

Kindly take a look at the HTML and CSS codes I've used, but I'm not still arriving at sample on the screen shot above.

```
HTML

    <div class="category">

    <div><a href="#"><img class="featured" src="images/Featured-Ad.jpg"></a></div>

    <div class="Categories">
    <div class="cat1-9">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Cars-n-Bikes.jpg" width="16.6%"  ></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Electronics-n-Appliances.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Mobile-n-Tablets.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Real-Estate.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Jobs.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Home-n-Lifestyle.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Education-n-Learning.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Services.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Community&Events.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Entertainment.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/Restaurants.jpg" width="16.6%"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/View-More.png" width="16.6%"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

CSS

    .featured{
        width:25%;

    }

    .category{
        display: -webkit-flex;
        border:10px solid #F00;
        display:flex;
        min-height:250px;
        margin:10px;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }

    .cat{
        max-width:140px;
        margin:2px;
        justify-content: right;


    }

    .cat1-9{
        margin:5px;
        width:70%;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Moon Cheesez for your interest to help, Please find my HTML and CSS Codes above.

Answer (score 0):

### Layout

#### Content Nodes

- `display: table-cell` to each anchor.

#### Minor Containers

- Wrapped a `div.row` around each of the 3 groups that has 3 anchors.
- Wrapped a `div.row` around the last group of 6.
- Assigned `display: table-row` to each `div.row`
- Wrapped a `section` around the first 3 groups and another `section` on the last row.

#### Primary Containers

- Made `#feature` `display: inline-block`.
- Wrapped a `section` around the 3 rows of 3, calling it `#r3c3`. Gave it `display: inline-table`.
- Wrapped a `section` around the 1 row of 6, calling it `#r1c6`. Gave it `display: table`.
- Wrapped everything with `main#primary`, assigned it `display: flex`, `flex-flow: row wrap`.

#### Flex Order

1. `#feature` `order: 1`
2. `#r3c3` `order: 2`
3. `#r1c6` `order: 3`

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>37639329</title>
<style>
*, *:after, *:before { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 none transparent; box-sizing: border-box; }
#primary { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; width: 640px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }
#feature { order: 1; display: inline-block; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 20px 3px 15px 11px; }
#r3c3 { order: 2; display: inline-table; table-layout: fixed; border-spacing: 5px; border: 1px solid transparent; }
#r1c6 { order: 3; display: table; border-spacing: 5px; border: .5px solid transparent; margin: -15px 0 0 0; }
.row { display: table-row; }
a { display: table-cell; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
img { display: block; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<main id="primary">
  <section id="feature">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" width="300" height="300">
    </a>
  </section>
  <section id="r3c3">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/000/fff?text=1">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/00f/fc0?text=2">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/302/fa6?text=3">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/33b/0ff?text=4">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/fff/000?text=5">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f3f/880?text=6">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/840/010?text=7">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/a77/954?text=8">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/b0b/edd?text=9">
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="r1c6">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ad5/73c?text=A">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/d91/e10?text=B">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f00/fff?text=C">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/6e8/e0e?text=D">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f07/fc0?text=E">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f80/07f?text=F">
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried using what you supplied but unfortunately, it didn't quite work like I wanted, so I decided to leave it this way https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyg7j0csfh4xjhr/Screenshot%202016-06-14%2010.45.59.png?dl=0 many thanks for your assistance. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Yeah, layouts are hard to get right if you are using a CMS or some similar environment. Well I'm glad you worked it out. A late reply is better than none, thank you.